# How can I convert a string to a double and a Int to a string in my C# project?

Tags: c#-4.0

I am trying to convert an Int to a string for my project and it will not work the way I want
And the same thing is happening with my string to double it will not work.

Here is the code I have tried to get it to work
`string StartingPopulation; double.Parse(StartingPopualtion);`
And the same thing with the int to string
`int PopulaitonAfterTenYears; string.Parse(PopulationAfterTenYears);`
How can I get it to work?

Comment: Please edit your question and describe what you mean by "will not work".  What exactly is happening?  Are you getting an error?  If so, what is the error?

Comment: Please share the specific error along with the full code snippet.  What do you mean by "will not work"?  That is too vague for us to help you.  What are the string values of those variables that you are trying to parse into numeric types?  You can use the {} button in the editor to make a text section look like code.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have values assigned to those variables. I would also recommend using TryParse instead.

```
string StartingPopulation = "0";
double.TryParse(StartingPopulation, out double result);
int PopulaitonAfterTenYears = 0;
string PopulaitonAfterTenYearsResult = PopulaitonAfterTenYears.ToString();
```